# Yii Ajax success Javascript won't go away

Tags: ajax, yii

I'm running Apache2 on Ubuntu 12.10, and yii 1.1.13

I have an ajax request that looks like this:

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList(
    'id',
    $model->value,
    $model->values,
    Array(
        'ajax' => array(
            'type'=>'POST', 
            'url'=>CController::createUrl('myurl'),
            'update'=>'#myId', 
            'data'=>array(
                'first'=>'value',
                'second'=>'value',
        ),
    )
);
```

In the past, I tried adding a line after 'data' that looked like this:

'success'=>"function(html){jQuery("#myId").html(html)}});return false;}"

I've since deleted it. For some reason, this keeps showing up on my page.

I've tried the following:

- Restarting entire server
- Deleting entire browser cache, and even having a friend who has never seen the site before load it
- Grep my entire web directory for that line of code

I have not been able to find any trace of this stupid line, but it won't go away. Please help, I'm starting to question my sanity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'update'=>'#myId', // this line indicates which selector would be updated after ajax success
```

Because above line also renders the same what the removed code acts

```
'success'=>"function(html){jQuery("#myId").html(html)}})
```

Comment: awesome, thanks. I think I got it. I wish I could upvote, but not enough reputation.